# re_msgs package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi every one,

how can i install re_msgs package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46796/re_msgs-package/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2012-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this [page](http://ros.jsk.imi.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/roswiki/re_msgs.html).

First you should

$ svn co https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest/re_msgs

and then rosmake that package.

(I already rosmake ths package successfully, so this should work for you. If you had SSL handshake failed issues, you can leave a comment, I met that issue when I was doing the first step.)

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0